# How to make one column fixed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

There is one scheme and different items inside it, so the scenario is that if user send SchemeID to the procedure then it should return the SchemeName(once) and all items inside a scheme i.e. DescriptionOfitem, Quantity, Rate, Amount... in this format

```
SchemeName DescriptionOfItems Quantity Unit Rate     Amount
 Scheme01      Bulbs             2       M2  200      400
               Titles            10      M3  300      3000
               SolarPanels       2       M2  1000     2000
               Bricks            50      M9  50       2500
                                             Total    7900
```

My try, it works but it also repeats the SchemeName for each row and can't find total

```
Select
    Schemes.SchemeName, 
    ContractorsWorkDetails.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemDescription,
    ContractorsWorkDetails.ContractorsWorkDetailsUnit, 
    ContractorsWorkDetails.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemQuantity,
    ontractorsWorkDetails.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemRate,
    ContractorsWorkDetails.ContractorsWorkDetailsAmount
From ContractorsWorkDetails
Inner Join Schemes
    ON Schemes.pk_Schemes_SchemeID= ContractorsWorkDetails.fk_Schemes_ContractorsWorkDetails_SchemeID
Where ContractorsWorkDetails.fk_Schemes_ContractorsWorkDetails_SchemeID= 2
```

Update:

I tested the query as suggested below but it gives this kinda result

[image]

Comment: Do you know you can use aliases for tables? Second you should use `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((cols),())` [GROUPING SETS doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get exactly what you need, just try it is rather easy

Comment: I can't see how it would be possible to avoid duplicating the scheme name without returning separate result sets. Nevertheless, duplicating them might not necessarily be such a bad thing - something you might still want to consider doing anyway.

Comment: This is the responsibility of the display layer, not SQL.  Whatever you're using to display the data (app, report, etc.) should suppress the repeats - DON'T try to do it in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total using `grouping sets`.  I would advise you to keep the schema name on each row.  If you want it filtered out on certain rows, then do that at the application layer.

Now, having said that, I think this will do what you want in SQL:

```
Select (case when GROUPING(cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemDescription) = 0
             then 'Total'
             when row_number() over (partition by s.SchemeName
                                     order by cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemDescription
                                    ) = 1
              then s.SchemeName else ''
        end) as SchemeName, 
       cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemDescription,
       cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsUnit, 
       cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemQuantity,
       cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemRate,
       SUM(cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsAmount) as ContractorsWorkDetailsAmount
From ContractorsWorkDetails cwd Inner Join
     Schemes s
     ON s.pk_Schemes_SchemeID = cwd.fk_Schemes_ContractorsWorkDetails_SchemeID
Where cwd.fk_Schemes_ContractorsWorkDetails_SchemeID = 2
group by GROUPING SETS ((s.SchemeName, 
                         cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemDescription,
                         cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsUnit, 
                         cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemQuantity,
                         cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemRate
                        ), s.SchemeName)
Order By GROUPING(cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemDescription),
         s.SchemeName, cwd.ContractorsWorkDetailsItemDescription;
```

The reason you don't want to do this in SQL is because the result set no longer has a relational structure:  the ordering of the rows is important.

Comment: Sir error 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'when'.

Comment: you have `when when` on 3rd line.

Comment: sorry my UPDATED Question @Hogan